# How to test flash component with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have following view component in my rails application

```rb
class Elements::FlashComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def initialize(*)
    super
  end

  def flash_class(level)
    case level
    when "notice"
      "alert alert-info"
    when "success"
      "alert alert-success"
    when "error"
      "alert alert-danger"
    when "alert"
      "alert alert-warning"
    end
  end
end
```

and i'd like to test it with rspec test

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Elements::FlashComponent, type: :component do
  it "renders flash notification" do
    with_controller_class Customer::DashboardController do
      flash.now[:notice] = "Notification message!"
      render_inline described_class.new()
    end

    expect(rendered_component).to have_text "Notification message!"
    expect(rendered_component).to have_selector "label"
    expect(rendered_component).not_to have_selector "img"
  end
end
```

But every time I run tests I see the following message

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ElementsFlashComponent "renders flash notification"
```

how to fix it?

Comment: You don't need a case statement here - just use a hash as its a 1-1 mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i've fixed it adding `controller.` before flash:

```rb
    with_controller_class Customer::DashboardController do
      controller.flash[:notice] = "Notification message!"
      render_inline described_class.new()
    end
```